# US date format on VBA import

Tags: excel, vba

Bloody annoying US dates again, this one I've not seen a solution on my many, many searches.

I have a bit of VBA I found that pulls in data from some **htm** files generated by our business partner in Detroit:

```
Dim DirPath As String
Dim I_Row As Integer
Dim FilePath As String
Dim xCount As Long
DirPath = ipsosFolder
If DirPath = "" Then Exit Sub
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
FilePath = Dir(DirPath & "\*.htm")
Do While FilePath <> ""
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;" _
      & DirPath & "\" & FilePath, Destination:=Range("A1"))
    .Name = "a"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .WebSelectionType = xlAllTables
    .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
    .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
    .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
    .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
    .WebDisableDateRecognition = True
    .WebDisableRedirections = False
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    FilePath = Dir
    End With
Loop
```

(Note the `.WebDisableDateRecognition = True`, that was my first hope at fixing this, have Excel ignore the americanised dates until I could do something to fix them.)

So there's dates in here formatted in the US way - 09/21/2022 for today, for example. Now, this particular date is of no concern as here in Australia, it's invalid, there is no 21st month and I can easily fix this up with a quick `=RIGHT(LEFT(B2,5),2)&"/"&LEFT(B2,2)&"/"&RIGHT(B2,10)` but my problem comes in when we get to dates like 09/12/2022 as there is a 9th of December as well as 12th of September and Excel, very kindly, converts this to a date integer which breaks the above code as the left / right is no longer referencing 09/12/2022 but 44904.

Anyone with a suggestion on what I can do stop Excel "helping" and converting the dates to an American interpretation - I've been over the machine and double checked all the windows settings are for the correct date format here.

The big issue is I need to compare these dates against some dates we have pulled in from another dataset that're in the "proper" format of d/m/y and not m/d/y like only the Americans seem to insist on using, so need to retain them as dates and accurate = \

Comment: You could try looking at the number formats of the date column(s) post-import: if a cell's format is "General" then you can apply the approach used in the formula you posted.  If it's date you can use a different formula to swap the day and month components to create the correct date. Eg: `=DATE(YEAR(B3),DAY(B3),MONTH(B3))`   If you want it all in a formula you could maybe use (eg) `CELL("format", B3)` to switch between the two approaches.

Comment: So, saying that the  (US) `Date` having month less or equal to 12 are converted swapping day with month and **the other ones  remain strings/text**, would be a correct understanding of your situation?

Answer (score 1):

If **(US) Date having month less or equal to 12 are converted swapping day with month and the other ones remain strings/text**, please use the next function:

```
Function convertUSStr_DateToAU(arr As Variant) As Variant
    Dim arrConv, arrStrD, i As Long
    ReDim arrConv(1 To UBound(arr), 1 To 1)
    For i = 1 To UBound(arrConv)
        If IsNumeric(arr(i, 1)) Then
            arrConv(i, 1) = DateSerial(Year(arr(i, 1)), Day(arr(i, 1)), Month(arr(i, 1)))
        Else
            arrStrD = Split(arr(i, 1), "/")
            arrConv(i, 1) = DateSerial(CLng(arrStrD(2)), CLng(arrStrD(0)), CLng(arrStrD(1)))
        End If
    Next i
    convertUSStr_DateToAU = arrConv
End Function
```

It can be used in the next way:

```
Sub testConvertUSStr_DateToAU()
     Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arrD
     Const Col As String = "B" 'column letter where the data to be correctly converted exists
     
     Set sh = ActiveSheet
     lastR = sh.Range(Col & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
     
     arrD = sh.Range(Col & 2 & ":" & Col & lastR).Value2 'Date is taken as number...
     arrD = convertUSStr_DateToAU(arrD)
     'drop the converted array content and format it appropriately:
     With sh.cells(2, Col).Offset(, 1).Resize(UBound(arrD), 1)
            .Value2 = arrD
            .NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyy"
     End With
End Sub
```

You must have **an empty column** immediately after the one to be converted/processed. The actual code returns the converted array in that empty column. But, only to let you check that it returned **exactly what you need**...

If so, you should modify the `With` statement range by only removing `.Offset(, 1)`. In this way it will return exactly in the original column needing to have the converted `Date`.